# Solving for $\alpha$ if $2 \sin(40^\circ)=\frac {\sin^2(\alpha)}{\sin(40^\circ+\alpha)\sin(70^\circ+2\alpha)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $\alpha$ if

$$2 \sin(40^\circ)=\frac {\sin^2(\alpha)}{\sin(40^\circ+\alpha)\sin(70^\circ+2\alpha)}$$

I got this equation while bashing a geometry question using sine law. I tried to use product rules but failed to solve it. Any help to solve it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are values of $\sin 40^∘$ and $\sin 70^∘$ pre-requisites? Then, the question only involves using the following formula: $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A.$$ Or are  you only given the standard $\sin$ values for angles $0^∘,30^∘,45^∘,60^∘,90^∘$.